# removing/stripping all html tags from sql files

Tags: html, sql, scripting, strip

I'm trying to strip all words starting with '<' and ending with '>' (HTML) from around 100 sql scripts. I've tried using sed.exe but i just don't quite understand how it works. I've made this program in a batch file and when i'm trying to run it trough command it says "access denied". Anyone any hints or tips how i should get this to work? Or maybe there is an easier/better way??
I'm very new to DOS and batch files so be easy on me!

Help is much appreciated!

```
    @echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set servername= <cut out>
    set dbname=<cut out>
    set spath="C:\Users\User\eenmaalandermaalbatch\Scripts"
    set CD = "C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\sed.exe"


    set hr=%time:~0,2%
    if "%hr:~0,1%" equ " " set hr=0%hr:~1,1%
    set logfilepath=                         %spath%\output_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%hr%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.        log
    set cmd='dir %spath%\*.sql /b/s'


    REM LOOP TROUGH ALL SCRIPTS AND FILTER THEM
    FOR %%G IN (%cmd%) DO (
        SED = "C:\Users\User\eenmaalandermaalbatch\Scripts" >         "C:\Users\User\eenmaalandermaalbatch\Scripts\test"
        sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g' "%%G" 
        sed '/insert/{x;p;x;}' "%%G" 
        sed 's/^[ \t]*//'  "%%G" 
        sed '/^ *$/d' "%%G" 
    )
```

Comment: Try visual basic scripting, files that ends with .vbs, and use the function Substring(yourtext, "<", "").


https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx


 also make sure the file is not read-only by right click and properties

Answer (score 0):

Try visual basic scripting, files that ends with .vbs, and use the function Substring(yourtext, "<", "").

Also make sure the file is not read-only by right click and properties

Comment: with file you refer to the files i'm running trough?